# Is it always necessary to create Dim tables?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, multidimensional-array

I have a fact table that will have a column which will hold one of two values (occupied/vacant).  Is it necessary to create a Dim table for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a count of cases then Occupancy is a measure with values 0/1 and not a dimension, so you wouldn't have a dimension table.

If you want to, I dunno, analyse Rents & Taxes by Occupancy and Region then Occupancy is a dimension. Again it should be stored as 0/1 because reducing column width is imperative in the Fact Table. Your reporting tool may allow you store a translation of 0/1 as metatdata, but you are better off with a dimension table, because this keeps your data warehouse application neutral.